# What are the names written on the back of Yuri Nazarov's photograph?

Tags: noir

In episode 6 of *Noir*, Kirika brings Yuri Nazarov home after he faints and finds [a family photograph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c7DFP.jpg) hidden behind a drawing of a cat. (See link for bigger version of image below.) On the back of the photograph, there is something written in what is probably Russian.

[image: back side of Nazarov's family photograph]

What is written on the back of the photograph? I have at best an extremely poor knowledge of the Cyrillic alphabet and the Russian language, so I have not managed to read everything written there. My guesses so far are, going line by line:

1. Ivanov
2. Natasha
3. Yuri
4. [I can't figure out what the middle two letters are.]
5. Balkutsk 1951 [This is the line that Kirika reports to Mireille, so it must be correct.]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your guesses are correct. Some of the Cyrillic letters here are written in a strange way: nobody writes ш ("sh") on the second line in this way. The letter и on the third line  has an underline that doesn't really belong. Abstracting away such gratuitous elements, I think the fourth line is "Миша" (Misha, a masculine name) in which the two middle letters are distorted with extraneous pen strokes. The full text for completeness:

> Иванов
>   Наташа
>   Юрий
>   Миша
>   Балкутск 1951

Presumably, the photograph depicts one female (Наташа) and two males (Юрий, Миша), with "Иванов" being their last/family name. (Actually, in Russian the family name would be written in plural form, i.e., "Ивановы"). Балкутск being the town where the photo is taken in 1951.

Comment: Thanks: I thought it might be Misha but it bothered me how the middle letters weren't written the way they were for "Natasha" and "Yuri" (particularly with the line over the second letter), so taking into account my lack of Russian knowledge I figured a second opinion would be helpful.